# python 3 EOFError: EOF when reading a line %%bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, eoferror

```
%%writefile mains_script.py
from math import pi

def mains():
    def circle_area(r):
        return pi * (r ** 2)

    def circle_circumference(r):
        return  2 * pi * r

    radius = float(input("Enter radius: "))
    print("Area =", circle_area(radius))
    print("Circumference =", circle_circumference(radius))

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    mains()
```

---

```
%%bash

python3 mains_script.py
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mains_script.py", line 23, in <module>
    mains()
  File "mains_script.py", line 16, in mains
    radius = float(input("Enter radius: "))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I treid try, exceptEOFError:break. it returns "break outside loop"

```
    def circle_circumference(r):
        return  2 * pi * r

    try:
        radius = float(input("Enter radius: "))
        print("Area =", circle_area(radius))
        print("Circumference =", circle_circumference(radius))
    except EOFError:
        break

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    mains()
```

---

```
  File "mains_script.py", line 21
    break
    ^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

I tried try,except EOFError: return too. it just print radius:, then stops there.
Please help.

ignore for word requirementsignore for word requirementsignore for word requirements

Comment: `break` will only work for loops, you probably want `pass`, though it would be better to understand why this is happening in the first place. I'm not sure what "reading a line %%bash" means? How exactly are you inputting data?

Comment: @roganjosh I tried pass, it just printed radius, then stops there....

Comment: %%bash is a magic command to run py file within jupyter

Comment: Yep, just found it sorry. I'm on Windows so that magic method doesn't work for me. I won't be able to reproduce sorry.